# Tuning MySQL/MariaDB

Tags: database, mysql, performance-analysis

I am looking for a tool for identify and fix ddbb performance tuning problems.
It must be free.

I know the existence of **mysqltuner** and **tuning-primer** but still I haven't try it.
Can anyone explain me what should I prefer?

Is there other solutions?

My system has:

- CentOS 7 x64 (Linux)
- RAM 5 GB
- 6 cores AMD

The network traffic is 30 GB/month and 400k usr/month

Comment: please explain your performance problem

Comment: When there are peaks of activity the database is blocked and you have to stop it and restart it to keep responding to requests. The service remains inactive (dead)

Comment: please update your question with stats such as number of users, some idea about concurrency, instance size (memory/cpu) and memory/cpu statistics when it is under load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I have seen so far, it is usual to use both scripts, because of the simplicity of their execution and clarity in the results.

In short, they save a lot of setup and testing time and their results are quite reliable, defining each action in detail.

Here you have the links and the command line of each one:

[MySQLTuner](https://github.com/major/MySQLTuner-perl)

```
# perl mysqltuner.pl
```

[Tuning-Primer](https://github.com/BMDan/tuning-primer.sh)

```
# sh Tuning-primer.sh
```